# Use multiple inheritance to satisfy abstract base class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, mixins

Why exactly doesn't this work? Are the inherited function signatures subtly incorrect or is the abstract base class enforced "before" the member functions are inherited or is it something else? Could this be convinced to work without function wrappers?

```
#include <iostream>

struct AbsBase {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

struct ProvideFoo {
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
};

struct ProvideBar {
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }
};

struct Concrete : public ProvideFoo, public ProvideBar, public AbsBase {
    // I guess I could put function wrappers here... sigh...
    //void bar() {ProvideBar::bar();}
    //void foo() {ProvideFoo::foo();}
};

int main() {
    Concrete c;
    c.foo();
    c.bar();
}
```

Comment: That's not how inheritance works.

Comment: What is "that"? More formally, why does the compiler tell me Concrete has a pure virtual member rather than telling me that multiple base classes contain the member, does that help?

Comment: @Praxeolitic Your question's wording has absolutely nothing to do with the sample you are showing here! There isn't anything _abstract_ :-/ ...

Comment: Huh? AbsBase has pure virtual functions and so is an "abstract class".

Comment: I really don't understand why you hate this question so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why your code fails to compile

I think the downvoters are a bit harsh on you, as your reasoning to supply the implementations of the two pure virtual functions through separate classes has some intuitive appeal.

Alas, you are doing two unrelated things at the same time. `ProvideFoo` and `ProvideBar` are completly unrelated to the `AbsBase` abstract class. You could also subclass both of them from `AbsBase`, but then each of them would still be an abstract class. In either case, your current `Concrete` is an abstract class because it derives from at least one class with a pure virtual function. You can't create objects from such classes.

### Fixing your code, part I

The easiest way is to drop subclassing from `AbsBase` altogether and subclass from `ProvideFoo` and `ProvideBar` directly. Of course, now you don't have `virtual` functions inside `Concrete`, so further subclassing can't easily override `foo` and `bar` functionality.

```
#include <iostream>

struct ProvideFoo {
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
};

struct ProvideBar {
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }
};

struct Concrete : public ProvideFoo, public ProvideBar {};

int main() {
    Concrete c;
    c.foo();
    c.bar();
}
```

[**Live Example I**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e23bb7777264011f)

### Fixing your code, part II

You can also create multiple interfaces and multiple concrete implementations, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct AbsFoo {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct AbsBar {
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

struct ProvideFoo: AbsFoo {
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
};

struct ProvideBar: AbsBar {
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }
};

struct Concrete : public ProvideFoo, public ProvideBar {};

int main() {
    Concrete c;
    c.foo();
    c.bar();
}
```

[**Live Example II**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac23cde079a95ab6)

### Fixing your code, part III

Now for the encore: you can also use `virtual` inheritance when subclassing `ProvideFoo` and `ProvideBar` from `AbsBase` by using the `virtual` keyword

```
#include <iostream>

struct AbsBase {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

struct ProvideFoo: virtual AbsBase {
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
};

struct ProvideBar: virtual AbsBase {
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }
};

struct Concrete : public ProvideFoo, public ProvideBar {};

int main() {
    Concrete c;
    c.foo();
    c.bar();
}
```

This is really advanced C++ and can become really complicated if your classes also contain member data. I would prefer to use the 2nd solution for your code.

[**Live Example III**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd2aac0e7c391dfb)

Comment: But ProvideBar and ProvideFoo don't inherit from AbsBase, are they somehow abstract in the context of Concrete?

Comment: You can also use virtual inheritance ;)

Comment: @dyp thanks, updating, but this goes really deep and a little knowledge is a dangerous thing :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make this clear in the question but I really did want to know literally why the code didn't compile. TemplateRex gave an awesome answer to the question as I asked it.

That said, here's an explanation of why the code doesn't compile and but also doesn't complain about an ambiguous member name. First, here's something similar that does compile.

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A::foo()\n"; };
};

struct B {
   void foo() { std::cout << "B::foo()\n"; }
};

struct C : public A, public B {};

int main() {
    // This is fine.
    C c;
    // Uncommenting the next line would cause an ambiguous member name lookup and
    // invalidate the program.
    //c.foo();
}
```

Fortunately, our program is not necessarily ill-formed just because an ambiguous name lookup can occur. Our program is ill-formed if an ambiguous name lookup does occur. 10.2.7

It is possible to create a valid program with c.foo() uncommented by adding even more definitions of foo().

```
// Name lookup never proceeds to the base classes if it succeeds locally. 10.2.4
struct C : public A, public B {
    void foo() { std::cout << "C::foo()\n"; }
};
```

Changing A to an abstract class by making A::foo() a pure virtual function prevents compilation.

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B {
   void foo() { std::cout << "C::foo()\n"; }
};

struct C : public A, public B {};

int main() {
    // This is illegal.
    C c;
    // The next line is irrelevant.
    //c.foo();
}
```

The compiler error indicates that struct C is abstract. Why? Let’s start with exactly what it means to be an abstract class.

"10.4 Abstract classes

2 An abstract class is a class that can be used only as a base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it. A class is abstract if it has at least one pure virtual function.
"

Apparently C has at least one pure virtual function and so is an abstract class and we can only inherit from it. Before getting to why C has a pure virtual function, we can already answer part of the question. C is an abstract class and we tried to create an instance, that's illegal. Simply *creating* the object is illegal. It doesn’t matter if you never try to access a pure virtual function.

So why does C have a pure virtual function? It must be A::foo(). What happened to B::foo()? Did A::foo() somehow take priority?

First, we usually say derived classes “have” functions they inherit but this obscures what's really going on.

"
10.1.4 [...] For each distinct occurrence of a non-virtual base class in the class lattice of the most derived class, the most derived object (1.8) shall contain a corresponding distinct base class subobject of that type. […]
"

Here it’s made clear that a derived class and base class remain distinct. We don't merely inherit a pile of functions. Now the difference between overriding a member and having access to more than one identically named members is clear. We can inherit multiple functions with identical names and signatures. We can even refer to the separate functions if we’re careful with scope but an ambiguous name lookup is illegal.

To not be an abstract class, inherited pure virtual functions must be *overridden*. We are indeed inheriting a pure virtual function that is not being overridden and so we have an abstract class. Incidentally we’re also inheriting a non-pure virtual function with an identical signature, but that’s just irrelevant trivia.